# Hibernate/JPA Legacy Table Issue with component keys for OneToMany join

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Our company just started researching if Hibernate/JPA is right approach for their legacy tables. 
 The requirement is to relate two tables with @OneToMany. The owing table table1 have ids id1 id2, table2 has id1, id2 and id3. There is no association table. The generated query should have added clause "id3=0". Is there a way to add fake id in table1 with constant value 0.

I have tried following two options. None of them are working.

1)

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "MVCMP, referencedColumnName = "VICMP"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "MVVND#", referencedColumnName = "VIVND#"),
    @JoinColumn(name = seq , referencedColumnName = "VISEQ#")
}) 
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "VISEQ# = 0") 
private List<VendorInternationalEntity> vendorInternational;
```

2)

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="mas_int", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name =  "MVCMP#"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MVVND#"))
@WhereJoinTable(clause="VISEQ#=0")
private List<VendorInternationalEntity> vendorInternational;
```

Any insight will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean when you state that none of them are working? Can you post the table definitions and the queries issued by Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "MVCMP, referencedColumnName = "VICMP"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "MVVND#", referencedColumnName = "VIVND#")
})
@Where(clause = "VISEQ#=0")
private List<VendorInternationalEntity> vendorInternational;
```